# Shelving and reviewing code in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, shelving

I want to shelve code changes in SVN for the main purpose of code reviews. I'm having a few problems and was hoping someone could check to see if I'm doing anything wrong.

I have set up the repository to have this extra structure:

```
/shelves
    /username1
    /username2
```

Then to create a shelf I am right-clicking the root folder of my working directory, clicking <kbd>Branch/Tag...</kbd>, browsing to the correct path (e.g. `/shelves/username1/MYPROJECT_29012013`), selecting <kbd>Working copy</kbd>, and finally <kbd>OK</kbd>.

To review the code in my shelf, I am going to the <kbd>Repo Browser</kbd>, browsing to the shelf branch, right-clicking it and choosing <kbd>Show Log</kbd>. This brings up a popup with a list of files in the lower half. Double-clicking on any of these files brings up a diff of the changes. Magic!

This works perfectly on a little test repo I have created on my machine. On our actual code base (with a remote repo), I get an error when I double-click a file for the diff. It says

```
"URL http://.../the/file/I/changed.cpp doesn't exist"
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is this likely a bug? Is there a better way to implement shelving and code reviews in `TortoiseSVN`?

EDIT: This process works fine for my colleague who is on TortoiseSVN 1.7.5 (SVN 1.7.3). I am on TortoiseSVN 1.7.10 (SVN 1.7.7). So this is likely a bug? Or settings are different on my machine?

Comment: Can you check your problematic repo (diff) from pure command-line? And show log for this strange file? TSVN 1.7.11 - no errors found (for *my* repos - big or small)

Comment: Possibly the entries from your local repo are malformed. I recommend you to delete this branch and generate it again.

Comment: I think your are doing thing that want mean to be done. if you can replace to git

Answer (score 0):

If you have Stop on copy/rename  ticked on the lower left then please untick it. I think it is a bug since even if there is no previous revision for the file then tortoisediff shows blank on the left side of comparison